# Error: INTO specified more than once at or near "INTO"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Inside a postgresql function I'm trying to get two values selected from a table into two variables, but I get this error:

```
INTO specified more than once at or near "INTO"
```

This is the (pseudo)code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$ 
DECLARE
    a numeric;
    b varchar(20);
    c numeric;
BEGIN
    IF ... THEN
        ...

        SELECT x INTO a FROM t1 WHERE y = 1

        IF a > 5 THEN
            SELECT m, n INTO b, c FROM t2 WHERE ...;
            ...
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is just (as always) a **missing semicolon**.

Just add the missing semicolon on the first `SELECT` statement

```
[...]

    SELECT x INTO a FROM t1 WHERE y = 1; #missing semicolon

    IF a > 5 THEN
        SELECT m, n INTO b ...;
[...]
```

The `INTO specified more than once` error is generated from the second `SELECT` statement (when it finds a second `INTO`) and it doesn't suggest much about where to find the problem.

Comment: Ha, same problem here... and same reason. Missing semicolons never get old.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for - if you have been copying and pasting and you accidentally put an INTO into a CTE out of view (above somewhere).