# To assign more than 1 variable in the select

Tags: postgresql

I have a function with 3 variables (x,y,z), I need to assign the  values in one select statement....

bellow my function, but it's wrong

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.teste( )
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
 declare resultado boolean;
 x int;
 y int; 
 z int; 

BEGIN
  select raio, latitude, longitude into x, y, z  from veiculo_ancora limit 1 
    --- .... continue .... 
END;
$function$;
```

the error message...

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: INTO specified more than once at or near "into"
  Posição: 723
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INTO specified more than once at or near "into"
  Posição: 723

Comment: What is *wrong* with it exactly? Do you get an error message? What does it say? -- Are you sure you are using `;` after each statement? (Or is just a typo in the question itself?)

Comment: Yes, bellow the error message

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: INTO specified more than once at or near "into"
  Posição: 723
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INTO specified more than once at or near "into"
  Posição: 723

Comment: Are you **sure** it's not [the missing semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803586/error-into-specified-more-than-once-at-or-near-into)?

Comment: Was using dbeaver, I switched to pgadmin and it worked  =S

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT raio, latitude, longitude FROM veiculo_ancora LIMIT 1 INTO x, y, z;
```

instead?

Comment: I did it... 

select raio, latitude, longitude into x, y, z  from veiculo_ancora limit 1;

It worked fine in another tool, I was using dbeaver, in pgadmin worked.